# Magento 2: Dropdown function before "Place Order"

Tags: magento2, event-observer, payment, dropdown-attribute, place-order

Good day! i'm a newbie in magento, i've already created a custom payment method. I would like to replace the "success" and "fraud" into payment gateway e.g. Paypal & Paymaya. After Clicking "Place Order" will proceed to Paypal or Paymaya depends on what you choose in dropdown.[image]
is it possible to get those value from Observer? Please Help. Thank you in Advance.